# Jquery selector can not get string from variable but defined

Tags: jquery

```
function draw(Main,Num_Nodes,check) {
    for (var i=0;i<Num_Nodes;i++)
    {
      var window = $("#window");
      var newnode = $('<div></div>');
      var node = Main[i];

      **var name = String(node.Name); //1
      //var name = "LeCorbusier";//2**

      var name = name.replace(/\s+/g,"");    //remove ' '
      newnode.attr("id",name);         //set id for <div>

      function product(id0){          // change <div>
         $("#"+id0).css({"width":"50px","height":"50px","background":"#FFF780"});
      }

      product(name);
      window.after(newnode);
    }
}
//end
```

I think those two make name as string,the second one works and I've changed the `<div>` successfully,but the first one doesnt work and have changed nothing,I confirm node.Name is "LeCorbusier" and String() can change it to string.

Comment: "LeCorbusier" is already a string..... ?

Comment: `window.after`?!?! You have overwritten `window`???

Comment: @connexo um ..... `var window = $("#window");`

Comment: Are you trying to apply a style to a tag or create a new one?

Comment: Well you do not add it to the DOM so tell me how jQuery is supposed to select it from the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You do not add the element to the DOM, but you go looking for it there. So if you want to look it up, you got to add it to the document before you try to find it there.

You already have a reference to it, so why would you look it up? Just set it.

```
newnode.attr(...)
newnode.css({"width":"50px","height":"50px","background":"#FFF780"});
```